# calico-node rkt returns stage1-fly.aci.asc: no such file or directory

Tags: coreos, rkt, calico

I have a CoreOS beta (1185.2.0) installed.

I have the following systemd service file to start calico-node:

```
[Unit]
Description=Calico per-host agent
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Slice=machine.slice
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Environment=ETCD_CA_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem
Environment=ETCD_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1.pem
Environment=ETCD_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1-key.pem
Environment=CALICO_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING=true
Environment=HOSTNAME=10.79.218.2
Environment=IP=10.79.218.2
Environment=FELIX_FELIXHOSTNAME=10.79.218.2
Environment=CALICO_NETWORKING=true
Environment=NO_DEFAULT_POOLS=true
Environment=ETCD_ENDPOINTS=https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2379,https://coreos-3.tux-in.com:2379
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir /var/run/calico
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rkt run --inherit-env --stage1-from-dir=stage1-fly.aci  --volume=var-run-calico,kind=host,source=/var/run/calico --volume=modules,kind=host,source=/lib/modules,readOnly=false --mount=volume=modules,target=/lib/modules --volume=dns,kind=host,source=/etc/resolv.conf,readOnly=true --volume=etcd-tls-certs,kind=host,source=/etc/ssl/etcd,readOnly=true --mount=volume=dns,target=/etc/resolv.conf --mount=volume=etcd-tls-certs,target=/etc/ssl/etcd --mount=volume=var-run-calico,target=/var/run/calico --trust-keys-from-https quay.io/calico/node:v0.22.0
KillMode=mixed
Restart=always
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

welp.. the systemd fails with:

```
● calico-node.service - Calico per-host agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/calico-node.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2016-10-25 04:51:15 UTC; 9min ago
  Process: 1970 ExecStart=/usr/bin/rkt run --inherit-env --stage1-from-dir=stage1-fly.aci --volume=var-run-calico,kind=host,source=/var/
  Process: 4307 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir /var/run/calico (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1970 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 25 04:51:15 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Calico per-host agent.
Oct 25 04:51:15 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: calico-node.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 25 04:51:15 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: calico-node.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 25 04:51:15 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: calico-node.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 25 04:51:15 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: Stopped Calico per-host agent.
Oct 25 04:51:15 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: calico-node.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 25 04:51:15 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Calico per-host agent.
Oct 25 04:51:15 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: calico-node.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 25 04:51:15 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: calico-node.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

I tried setting the environment variables on terminal and running the rkt command and I got the error message

```
image: using image from file /usr/lib/rkt/stage1-images/stage1-fly.aci
run: open /usr/lib/rkt/stage1-images/stage1-fly.aci.asc: no such file or directory
```

I think that error may relate to the following configuration file at `/etc/rkt/paths.d/paths.json`

```
{
    "rktKind": "paths",
    "rktVersion": "v1",
    "stage1-images": "/usr/lib/rkt/stage1-images"
}
```

I need the paths configuration file later on for kubernetes.

any ideas? the asc file really doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/lib` is a dynamic link to `/usr/lib64`. rkt configured there not to search for certificates for container images at `/usr/lib64` and not `/usr/lib`.

it seems that by default this configuration is already set properly, so just removing the file `/etc/rkt/paths.d/paths.json` resolves the issue.

full answer at https://github.com/coreos/rkt/issues/3320